# Optional parameters in Fsharp records

Tags: properties, f#, nullable, records

I need to modify and add new property for my F Sharp record. but then it gives errors for the previous instances which are made without this new field. I made it as Nullable ,but still the same error occures, Please help me to solve this

Comment: This question is way to vague to answer, but I suspect the answer is the `with` keyword

Comment: you can add some code to the Q ?

Comment: Update the previous instances so they use the new field?

Comment: i have something like this  
type MedicalRecord = {
    Id:int
    /// Date of the medical record
    Date:string
    DateValue:DateTime
} 

i need to modify this to |
type MedicalRecord = {
    Id:int
    /// Date of the medical record
    Date:string
    DateValue:DateTime
    isModified:boolien
} 

but i have used this all over my code earlier ,so when those instances get awaken it gives the error saying that  parameters doesn't match 
 @Foggy Finder

Comment: @user3600790 - That's a *good* thing. It means the compiler is helping you keep your code up-to-date. In every place where you created an instance of that record type, you now have to look at the surrounding code and say, "Should `isModified` be false here? Am I sure? Is this, perhaps, one place where I should be setting `isModified` to true instead?" This will save you SO MUCH debugging time in the long run, because you'll fix bugs before they ever happen. The compiler is your friend.

Comment: @rmunn yeah i understood that and according to oop we have to give all the parameters ,But what i need to know was is there any kind of solution that i can neglect null able properties while invoking ,Because just think if there are 1000 objects created earlier in many places and then i add a new property ,so i have to add null to all these reference points

Comment: @Heshan - In that case, writing a constructor function (like the `Name.Create` example from Anton Schwaighofer's answer) is a good idea. Find all the places where the record is instantiated directly and replace them with calls to that function. Then when you add a nullable field, you only have to change one place. But be certain that you really do want null to be the default, because in that scenario, the compiler will no longer help you find all the parts of the code that instantiate the record. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: thank you ,highly appreciate all of your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume you mean "optional" as in "a field that I don't provide when instantiating the record". However, there is no such thing as an optional field in F# records unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your point of view). All record fields that you specify *must* be present at the point when you instantiate it.

See also [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634201/f-optional-record-field).

You may consider this trade-off:

- Use a **record**. Each time you update the record, the F# compiler will scream and alert you about all places where you used this record, and you need to now provide the additional information. The additional information can be a `None` for the fields you added, if they are options. The big advantage: Your code itself will not have to handle all of the possibly many cases of "what to do if `field1` is missing? What if `field2` is missing, too?"
- Use a **class**. When you update the class, the F# compiler will not enforce any sort of completeness check about the information you put into the class. (You can view records as classes where all fields are constructor arguments, and all must be provided). Hence, updating the class definition causes no overhead, but your code needs handle all the missing values.

I personally prefer records just because it *forces* me to think through the implications of adding a new field.

There is of course a middle ground: You can use records, but instantiate all of them via static members or something alike:

```
type Name = 
    { 
        First: string
        Family: string
    }        
    static member Create(first, family) = { First = first; Family = family}
```

If, in your code, you always use `Name.Create` to instantiate the record, you will of course be able to add a `MiddleName` field without any consumer code noticing.

Answer (score 5):

The [Option type](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/) is preferred over null in F#, for the simple reason that "uninitialized variables" do not exist in the functional way of thinking.

Let's start by building a record that represents a `VacationRequest`, which has to be approved by the boss.

```
type VacationRequest =
   {Name : string
    Date : DateTime
    Approval : string option}
```

The problem with your approach is that all fields have to be assigned on construction, so this won't compile:

```
let holiday =
   {Name = "Funk"
    Date = DateTime(2020,12,31)}
```

You can work around this using a helper function, which implicitly sets the option value.

```
let fillInRequest name date =
   {Name = name 
    Date = date 
    Approval = None}
```

Now you can build the record using the helper function.

```
let holiday = fillInRequest "Funk" <| DateTime(2020,12,31)
```

Did notice something funny when sending the code to FSI.

> ```
> val holiday : VacationRequest = {Name = "Funk";
>                                  Date = 31/12/2020 12:00:00 ;
>                                  Approval = null;}
> ```

The boss could then update the request (creating a **new** record)

```
let approvedHoliday =
    {holiday with Approval = Some "boss' name"}
```

> ```
> val approvedHoliday : VacationRequest = {Name = "Funk";
>                                          Date = 31/12/2020 12:00:00 ;
>                                          Approval = Some "boss' name";}
> ```

or send it back unaltered

```
let betterLuckNextTime = holiday
```