# How to represent an F# Type in C# with Empty parameters

Tags: f#

I'm trying to avoid creating a default object in F#, at least in its full capacity to that I can represent it in WPF.

I read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634201/f-optional-record-field) post .  So I tried implenting the type as a class, thinking that it would be optional in C# as well.

```
type OrderException(?id: Guid, ?orderId: Guid, ?orderNumber: string) = 
    member x.id = id
    member x.OrderID = orderId
    member x.OrderNumber = orderNumber
```

So - in F# I can create an empty object:

```
let orderException = new OrderException()
```

But if I use the library in C# and try to instantiate the object - then I get:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'id' of 'Artoo.OrderException.OrderException(FSharpOption, FSharpOption, FSharpOption)'    Zimpla.Windows  D:\Core\Zimpla\Zimpla.Windows\ViewModels\ResolveExceptionsViewModel.cs  26  N/A

So - back to square one. The only way I can see around this is to have an F# method that creates a "default" version of the object with nothing in it.

Comment: Unfortunately F# have 2 ways to declare optional parameters. One recognized only by F#, other by all languages, but requires extra writing, see paragraph with `<Optional; DefaultParameterValue<(...)>]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [F# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters):

> For the purposes of C# and Visual Basic interop you can use the attributes [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue<(...)>] in F#, so that callers will see an argument as optional. This is equivalent to defining the argument as optional in C# as in MyMethod(int i = 3).

```ml
type OrderException(
    [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue(Guid())>]id: Guid,
    [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue(Guid())>]orderId: Guid, 
    [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue("")>]orderNumber: string) = 
    member x.id = id
    member x.OrderID = orderId
    member x.OrderNumber = orderNumber
```

That said, a record with an `Empty` property is quite an idiomatic pattern and I'd favor this here.

```ml
type OrderException = 
  { Id: Guid
    OrderId: Guid
    OrderNumber: String }
with 
    static member Empty = 
      { Id = Guid.Empty
        OrderId = Guid.Empty
        OrderNumber = "" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want, it may also be worth using idiomatic F# style, like optional parameters in the `?id` format, but adding an overloaded default constructor. If you only need this for C# (or even WPF) then you could even annotate this with an attribute to produce a warning if the constructor is used from F#:

```
open System

type OrderException(?id: Guid, ?orderId: Guid, ?orderNumber: string) = 
    [<CompilerMessage("Default constructor should not be used from F#!",0)>]
    new() = OrderException(?id=None)
    member x.id = id
    member x.OrderID = orderId
    member x.OrderNumber = orderNumber

OrderException() // F# warning - should not be used!
OrderException(Guid.NewGuid()) // This is fine
```